# Where is all the mana going?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I'm wondering where do Mana that falls into bottomless pits goes. Is it lost forever? Is it going into my bank? What happens to it? Should I care of it falling down the pit or not?

Also, Mana despawns after a while... is the same thing happening to that mana?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it's possible for mana to despawn (if there's too much of it around, for instance), I believe that mana that ends up in inaccessible areas of the map would be considered "on the ground" and split between player banks at the start of the next phase:

> Any mana crystals on the ground at the beginning of a Combat Phase or at the end of a mission will be split among players and deposited directly into their banks.

This is quoted from the Dungeon Defenders Wikia entry for [Mana](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Mana), although I believe it's also a loading screen tip.

EDIT: And to confirm, a passage later in the page answers the second question:

> When the limit on the number of mana crystals on the map is reached, older crystals will despawn to make room for new ones. This limit is 30 on mobile versions. Because the limit is based on quantity instead of value, it is possible for older, more valuable crystals to be replaced by newer, less valuable ones. Crystals that despawn are lost and are not deposited into the bank.

Comment: Note that at least in the XBox version you can tell whenever the beginning of Combat Phase deposit occurs.  There is a message that briefly appears on screen that says the amount of mana deposited into players banks.

Comment: The "despawning" aspect means that it's important to spend mana during the combat phase - if I end up full, I try to drop upgrades while in-combat.

Comment: Lately I'm ripping off class abilities like it is going out of style, so I'm always eating mana on the ground.  Good to be aware of though.  I didn't realize the cap was so easy to hit.